# Post a image usining binairy and other data

Tags: mongodb, image, spring-boot, post, upload

Trouble adding image binairy to a model that has other properties as well. Photo model has title as wel ,without title I am able to save the image

```
//payee model
     public class Payee {
                        @Id
                        private String id; 
    private String name; 
                        private Photo photo;
                    
                    //photo model
                    public class Photo {
                    
                        @Id
                        private String id;
                        private String title;
                        private Binary image;
   //Constuctor
    //Getter and Setter

                //add photo
                     @PostMapping('/photos/add')
                        public String addPhoto(@RequestBody Payee payee , @RequestParam("title") String title, @RequestParam("image") MultipartFile image, Model model)
                                throws IOException {
                            String id = photoService.addPhoto(title,image);
                            return id;
                        }][1]][1]
```

Comment: `It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.`. Okay, I'll just repeat it three times :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

figured it out,
set image as binary in model

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/update", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = "multipart/form-data")
    public ResponseEntity<Payee> update(@RequestPart("payee") @Valid Payee payee, @RequestPart("file") @Valid MultipartFile image) throws IOException
    {
        // routine to update a payee including image
        if (image != null)
            payee.setImage(new Binary(BsonBinarySubType.BINARY, image.getBytes()));
        Payee result = payeeRepository.save(payee);
        return ResponseEntity.ok().body(result);
    }
```